# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser сохранить без форматирования

Tags: simple-html-dom, php

Я получаю код страницы, нормально отформатированный, красивый и читабельный код. Далее вношу изменения в адреса картинок, типа:

```
$get_html = new simple_html_dom();
                                $get_html->load_file($html_file);

                                //Проходимся по массиву адресов img
                                foreach ($get_html->find('img') as $element) {
                                    $path_img_array = explode('/', $element->src);
                                    $path_to_img = array_pop($path_img_array);
                                    $element->src = $config['dir_img'] . $path_to_img;
                                }
$get_html->save('index.html');
```

Но после сохранения, код этой страницы становится нечитабельный, удаляются все переносы и  табуляция. Как сделать чтобы сохранение через эту функцию не влияло на структуру ДОМ документа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы загружаете текст с помощью `load`, то нужно добавить следующие параметры в аргументы вызова:

```
$html= new simple_html_dom();
$text= "<div>\n    <span>\n        <span>text</span>\n    </span>\n</div>";
$html->load($text, $lowercase=true, $stripRN=false, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT);
$html->find('span',1)->innertext = "xxx";
$html->save('temp.txt');
```

Будут сохранены все переносы и отступы.

В случае `file_get_html` аргументов станет несколько больше:

```
$html= file_get_html("temp.txt", $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=false, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT);
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9388418/1299307)

Comment: Спасибо!) Помогло!